# How to disable the built in wifi and retain the plug-in wifi connection?

Tags: networking, wireless

I use Ubuntu 16:04 and I needed to buy a small usb wifi adapter as for some reason the built in wifi of my DELL laptop seems to pick the signal poorly.

The only problem now is that the built in signal also gets activated sometimes, when the laptop is closer to the wifi-source, and keeps reconnecting again, which is annoying. I just need to find a way to disable this built-in wifi and retain only the plug-in wifi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your both the cards are already connected to wifi network.

run `nmcli device`

example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ nmcli device
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlx001ea65a550b  wifi      connected     hasini 1   
wlp4s0           wifi      disconnected  --         
enp3s0           ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --         
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

Here in the above output
`wlx001ea65a550b` is the usb wifi adapter.
`wlp4s0` is the built in wifi adapter.

to disconnect the built in wifi adapter, run the below command.

```
nmcli device disconnect wlp4s0
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ nmcli device disconnect wlp4s0 
Device 'wlp4s0' successfully disconnected.
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

so add the command `nmcli device disconnect wlp4s0` to your startup applications like below.

[image]

Please note that these are variables..

```
wlx001ea65a550b  
wlp4s0
```

Replace above names with your output from the command `nmcli device`

Answer (score 0):

Read `man rfkill`, which begins:

```
rfkill - tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices
```